# how to add child component to parent component with event on sibling?

Tags: reactjs

I have below component structure.

```
Parent-wrapper
    Sibling 1 (input file type)
    Sibling 2 (image thumbnail)
```

When sibling 1 is changed with the uploaded file I want to add sibling 2 on to the parent. I want to show sibling 2 with a progress bar to show file is being uploaded.

I am confused how to couple child event on parent component. Any guidance on what I should be reading on? or any help is greatly appreaciated.

Comment: Are you using fetch api or axios for file upload?

Comment: Nope. I was thinking of using simple Ajax post. Using fetch /axioms will it make things easier?

Comment: Not sure if it will make it easier or harder but `fetch` doesn't have progress ability. You could still show **fake** progress bar tho. 
If the question is more structural and assuming I understood your question correctly you should keep a `state` about file was uploaded or not in the `parent` component and render `Sibling 2` if the value is `true` or something

Comment: Can you try something like the example I added here https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-ramanujan-mh2lh.

Answer (score 0):

Have a function say, `handleUploadFile` in the Parent component, and pass it as a prop to Sibling 1.

`Parent.js`

```
// ..code..
const handleUploadFile = (file) => {
  // make an api call to upload file, 
  // either fake progress or use a library that supports real progress
  this.setState({showUploadProgress:true})
    //on successful upload
      this.setState({showUploadProgress:false});
      this.setState({file});
}

render(){
  return(
    <Sibling2 uploadProgress={showUploadProgress} file={file}/>
    <Sibling1  onUploadFile={this.handleUploadFile}/>
  )
}

set file from sibling-1 to parent from callback.
```

`Sibling-1`

```
render(){
 return(
   //more views
   <input onChange = {(file) => {this.props.onUploadFile(file)}} type='file'/>
 )
}
```

Have logic in 1Sibling-2` to show/hide progress and image based on the received props.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Can you try something like the example I added here https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-ramanujan-mh2lh.

It does not have file upload code, it just shows the basic flow you can have in order to solve your problem. It has fake file upload progress.